# Titan remove many vertices has poor performance

Tags: performance, bulk, titan

## Improving performance when deleting multiple vertices?

I have a big graph in Titan (using rexster and cassandra) which I would like to be able to remove a potentially large portion of.

I want to delete everything a user "owns" which isn't in the provided list of IDs, and return the list of IDs of what they actually still "own" in the graph. I have tried these two approaches, both of which takes very long. I am testing with the worst-case scenario where `list_of_ids_to_keep` is empty(`[]`).

```
//A naive list-based approach
def delete_mulitple(graph, user_id, list_of_ids_to_keep)
{
    u = get_or_create_user(g, user_id)
    user_things = u.outE('owns').inV().collect{it.id}
    removees = user_things - list_of_ids_to_keep
    g.v(*(removees)).remove() //This is the slow part of this approach
    g.commit()
    return (user_things - removees)
}

//Approach using Hash to potentially reduce memory footprint and O-notation, but is still taking a long time.
def delete_multiple_hash(graph, user_id, list_of_ids_to_keep)
{
    def u = get_or_create_user(g, user_id)
    def user_things = u.outE('owns').inV().collect{it.id}
    def inUserGraph = [:]
    def keepers = [:]

    list_of_ids_to_keep.each { k_id ->
        inUserGraph[k_id] = true
    }

    user_things.each {k_id ->
        if (!inUserGraph[k_id]){
            g.v(k_id).remove() //Again: the remove is the slow part
        }
        else{
            keepers << k_id
        }
    }
    g.commit()
    return keepers
}
```

**Is there a way to improve the performance of this using some sort of bulk operation, turning off some checks, doing an async query, or applying some other strategy?**

I have already enabled "storage.batch-loading" which I though might improve performance. I measure the query times to be about 150 seconds, but then nothing is commited, so I believe it is timing out.

---

The layout of the graph is:

**User (-owns->) A Thing (-contains->) A Description (can be shared by multiple "A Thing"s)**

Numbers:

```
User -owns-> ~= 200K "A Thing"s. (g.v(user_id).outE('owns').count() ~= 200K)
A Thing -contains-> ~= 100 "A Description"s (g.v(a_thing_id).outE('contains').count() ~= 100)
A Description <-contains- ~= 100 "A Thing" (g.v(a_description_id).inE('contains').count ~= 100)
```

Comment: So, a single user can own about 200K things? In that case, the above transaction will definitely time-out since removing 200K things is too much for a single transaction. Try using Titan-Hadoop for such batch work loads (e.g. in pseudo-cluster mode).

Comment: These are worst-case, but yeah. It can happen that a user have 200K things that needs to be deleted. I will check out Titan-Hadoop, or see if I can split it up somehow.